# EC2 SSH port 22 connection refused even though previously worked

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance which i've got a couple of sites hosted on and it's previously been workin really nice.

Today I try to SSH into it and it just refusing connections on port 22 even though the security group has it open and the security group is set to the instance.

Anyone help me out as to why this could be the case?

I just get this line each time - ssh: connect to host 54.247.99.86 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: I mean I even used the same command that previously worked as well.

Comment: Sounds like your sshd may have gone down, as far as I remember you'd get a timeout if the firewall applied.

Comment: Not sure how I could restart that specifically though?

Comment: Someone else may have a better idea, but since you don't have any access to a command line without ssh, I can't see any way except an instance reboot. You may want someone else to double check the security group config before you take drastic measures though, just to make sure.

Comment: I have tried an instance reboot and it still refuses even after that. What do you think could be the best course of action. It weirdly otherwise still works fine - http://www.davidheward.com

Comment: Anything interesting show up in the console output during boot? In particular then of course messages regarding sshd.

Comment: Just found this Starting sshd: /var/empty/sshd must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.

[FAILED]

Comment: Not sure there's much I can do about that?

Comment: Also seen this ip-10-234-135-29 login: /dev/fd/11: line 1: /sbin/plymouthd: No such file or directory
initctl: Event failed

Comment: Not without rebuilding the image, no.

Answer (score 2):

If your instance is EBS based and not an Instance store then take an ami image first as a backup, then stop the instance, boot a new raw instance.

As your old instance is EBS based, detach the volume and attach it to new instance. Once attached mount it to some directory, change the permission /var/empty/sshd,  also do cat /etc/fstab to know where was your / partition mounted. Now umount the volume from new instance attach to the old instance with the exact mount point which you had when in fstab like /dev/sda1 for /.

Once attached, start the old instance and check whether you are able to login or not.

Comment: Ok going to give this a try, anything that will avoid having to rebuild the whole thing sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, you can follow the steps below to do so:

1. Launch a new instance in same region (so we can attach the EBS volume to it later).
2. Stop your current instance and detach the EBS volume
3. Attach that volume to the new instance at /dev/sdf.
4. SSH into the new instance and run the following command: sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt
5. Run this command: cat /mnt/etc/rc.d/rc.local

If the output contains these lines please remove it from the rc.local file:

```
    cat <<EOL >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    UseDNS no
    PermitRootLogin without-password
    EOL
```

6. After you modified the rc.local file you can un-mount the EBS volume,detach it from the temporary instance and attach it back to your original instance at /dev/sda1 . And you should be able to SSH into your instance.

This appears to be a temporary fix. This will reoccur if you reboot. I also looking for permanent fix.

Comment: Same problem for me after an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.i04. I don't have an rc.local file, so......?