# AWS EC2 Connection (SSH) says - Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I was just connected to the instance over ssh and Change permission on home directory to 755 using "sudo chmod -R 755 ./". After that, I can't execute any single commands through SSH shell. So I have disconnect and find my ec2 public IP has been changed. Now i am trying to connect with ec2 instance using .pem file, it says connection refused and port 22 is showing as closed.

Note: I have tried to reconfigure security group inbound rule for port 22 and stop,start my instance but none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means **sshd is down on your ec2 instance**.

**1st thing**: SSH is very sensitive to permissions; please refer to [ssh-and-home-directory-permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions)

**2nd thing**: change of public IP means the instance was stopped/started, not just disconnected; an EC2 does not lose its public IP without a stop/start.

So probably you broke your ssh access when changed permissions; and ssh might not have been enabled, so when you reboot the box, it was not started leading to **connection refused** error.

You can try to connect through the console and troubleshoot; or follow this question [EC2 SSH port 22 connection refused even though previously worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447438/ec2-ssh-port-22-connection-refused-even-though-previously-worked?rq=2)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, misexplained it; edited the answer.